# Built in "pairify" function in f#?

Tags: f#

Is there a built in function in f# with the signature `'a -> 'b -> 'a*'b`?

I realize it's super easy to just write `fun a b -> a, b`, but so is `fun a -> a` and we still have the [id function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.id%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

Example usage:

```
let pairify = fun a b -> a, b

[1;2;3] |> List.mapi pairify
```

Comment: Can you use `List.zip : 'T1 list -> 'T2 list -> ('T1 * 'T2) list`?

Comment: There is not. But for that specific example you can do `[1;2;3] |> List.indexed`

Comment: Didn't know of `List.indexed`, and couldn't find it in the docs. Apparently the docs are lacking: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualfsharpdocs/issues/184

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function `'a -> 'b -> 'a * 'b`, which is slightly annoying. If you are going down the route of providing your own, why not define a [global operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading#operators-at-the-global-level) instead?

```
let (=>) = fun a b -> a, b
1=>2
// val it : int * int = (1, 2)
```

This also makes it more obvious what is going on when e.g. providing key-value-pairs like `dict[1=>"a";2=>"b"]`. Your list indexing use case would become

```
[1;2;3] |> List.mapi (=>)
// val it : (int * int) list = [(0, 1); (1, 2); (2, 3)]
```

Comment: That's neat. It also shows that ',' is almost an operator, but with the magic signature of "('a * 'b * ...) -> 't -> 'a * 'b * ... * 't". It would be pretty cool if you could do "let tuplify = (,)" :)